# Raspberry PI Google Fuchsia OS installation

Tags: raspberry-pi3

Has anybody managed to install Google Fuchsia (1) on a raspberry pi?

on the Raspberry Pi 3 : https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/

(1): https://github.com/fuchsia-mirror/magenta

Comment: I'm not sure is this question suits here as it is not question about programming. I think it should be moved to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes of course. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

`fuchsia` kernel: `magenta` is possible to run on raspberry pi. I did it on Model 3b. Please find below link to run `magenta` on raspberry pi:

- [Magenta on raspberry pi](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/magenta/+/HEAD/docs/targets/rpi3.md)

Let me know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: Link is giving a 404?

Comment: @winwaed Google renamed Magenta to Zircon back in October and unfortunately .. they removed the page :!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible anymore.

Google removed support for RPI3 from Zircon Kernel(formally magenta). Couldn't find the exact commit but if you navigate at the [`target/arm64/board`](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/zircon/+/master/kernel/target/arm64/board/) tree you will see that the `rpi` dir is no more.